# Check if an IP address is in a IPNetwork with Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

With Pyspark, I would like to join/merge if an IP address in the dataframe A is in a IP network range or hits the same IP address in the dataframe B.

The dataframe A contains IP addresses only and the other one has IP addresses or IP addresses with a CIDR. Here is an example.

```
Dataframe A
+---------------+
|     ip_address|
+---------------+
|      192.0.2.2|
|   164.42.155.5|
|    52.95.245.0|
|  66.42.224.235|
|            ...|
+---------------+

Dataframe B
+---------------+
|     ip_address|
+---------------+
| 123.122.213.34|
|    41.32.241.2|
|  66.42.224.235|
|   192.0.2.0/23|
|            ...|
+---------------+
```

then an expected output is something like below

```
+---------------+--------+
|     ip_address| is_in_b|
+---------------+--------+
|      192.0.2.2|    true|  -> This is in the same network range as 192.0.2.0/23
|   164.42.155.5|   false|
|    52.95.245.0|   false|
|  66.42.224.235|    true|  -> This is in B
|            ...|     ...|
+---------------+--------+
```

The idea I first wanted to try is using a udf comparing one by one and checking an IP range when a CIDR comes up but it seems udfs don't multiple dataframes. I also tried to convert the df B to a list and then compare. However, it is very inefficient and takes a long time as the A row number*the B row number is over 100 million. Is there any efficient solution?

Edited:
For more detailed information, I used the following code to check without pyspark and using any library.

```
def cidr_to_netmask(c):
    cidr = int(c)
    mask = (0xffffffff >> (32 - cidr)) << (32 - cidr)

    return (str((0xff000000 & mask) >> 24) + '.' + str((0x00ff0000 & mask) >> 16) + '.' + str((0x0000ff00 & mask) >> 8) + '.' + str((0x000000ff & mask)))

def ip_to_numeric(ip):
    ip_num = 0
    for i, octet in enumerate(ip.split('.')):
        ip_num += int(octet) << (24 - (8 * i))

    return ip_num

def is_in_ip_network(ip, network_addr):
    if len(network_addr.split('/')) < 2:
        return ip == network_addr.split('/')[0]
    else:
        network_ip, cidr = network_addr.split('/')
        subnet = cidr_to_netmask(cidr)
        return (ip_to_numeric(ip) & ip_to_numeric(subnet)) == (ip_to_numeric(network_ip) & ip_to_numeric(subnet))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with "is in IP network range" logic- can you elaborate on that with an example? Also why are `52.95.245.0` and `66.42.224.235` showing as `false` in the output? Those are clearly in B. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pault I just wanted to show an output example so I modified the sample dataframes. For a network range, https://gist.github.com/tott/7684443 is a good example even in PHP. In Python, I usually use the `netaddr` library to do the same thing like `IPAddress(x) in IPNetwork(y)`. http://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_01.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use `crossJoin` and `udf`s, but with a cost of cartesian product

```
from pyspark.sql import *
data_1 = ["192.0.2.2", "164.42.155.5", "52.95.245.0", "66.42.224.235"]
data_2 = ["192.0.2.0/23", "66.42.224.235"]
DF1 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(ip=x) for x in data_1])
DF2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(ip=x) for x in data_2])

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
join_cond = udf(is_in_ip_network, BooleanType())

DF1.crossJoin(DF2).withColumn("match",join_cond(DF1.ip, DF2.ip))
```

The result looks similar to

```
ip          ip              match 
192.0.2.2   192.0.2.0/23    true
192.0.2.2   66.42.224.235   false
164.42.155.5    192.0.2.0/23    false
164.42.155.5    66.42.224.235   false
52.95.245.0 192.0.2.0/23    false
52.95.245.0 66.42.224.235   false
66.42.224.235   192.0.2.0/23    false
66.42.224.235   66.42.224.235   true
```

Comment: Thanks it worked well with dropping duplicates after the join. However, it still take too long as DF1 has around 10,000,000 rows and DF2 is around 10,000. Is there any way to optimise? DF1 has some duplicates IP addresses (All IPs in the DF2 are unique and I need to keep all the duplicates in the DF1.) so I wonder if I can use something like a memoisation technique with pyspark.

Comment: @andrewshih you can use a broadcast hash join, which will cache df2 on all the executors.

ex: large_df.join(broadcast(small_df), ["key"])